# FPDF Landscape image issue [PHP]

Tags: php, width, landscape, fpdf

I have a problem with FPDF in landscape mode. The whole text-stuff works pretty well.

But if I insert an image that is wider than 21 cm (8,27 inch), it jumps one line down. I tried to use

`$pdf -> setLineWidth(280);` but that doesn't work.

Does anybody know a solution on this issue?

Thanks a lot, greets

Julian

Comment: can you please write here code you are using ??

Comment: What works fine for you? The `setLineWidth();` function? I think it work for me too but it has no effect to the `Image();` function... Did you understand my problem? Maybe the more detailed description of my problem below is better.

Answer (score 1):

Of cause I can paste some code.
But it will never help you understanding my problem. It's just like it is.

```
$pdf = new FPDF("L", "mm", "A4");
$pdf -> Open();
$pdf -> SetMargins(6, 15);
$pdf -> AddPage();
$pdf -> SetAutoPageBreak(false);
$pdf -> Image("projekt.jpg", "150", "8", "60");
```

I place it 150 mm from left. Plus 60 mm width of the picture equals 210 mm, the exact width of an A4 page in Portrait mode.
But when I put the page into landscape mode (new width is about 290 mm), and place the image 151 mm from left, it jumps one line down.

So it seems as FPDF's `Image();` function doesn't recognize the document's orientation.

Maybe someone got a solution…